# Impala join with or query

Tags: join, cloudera, impala

I am trying to perform a join in impala as such:

```
Select * from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on (t1.column1 = t2.column1 OR t1.column2 = t2.column2)
```

But I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedException: Join with 't2' requires at least one conjunctive equality precidate.
To perform a Cartesian product between two tables, use a CROSS JOIN.
```

I have tried using a CROSS JOIN but it does not work either.

Is it possible to perform or queries on a join in Impala? Is there a work around?

I have tried it using and AND query and it runs successfully.

Any help or advice is appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested on the [Impala JIRA](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-408), you can trying rewriting your query with a UNION ALL clause. Unfortunately you'll have to do the deduplication following the UNION ALL manually.